# Why $(elem).height() returns height in pixels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In jquery when we do `$(elem).height()` or `.width()` then why do we get measurement in pixels
i.e if elem height is set to 200px then we get 200
and if we set elem height to 20% (say it is 200px) then also we get 200

Comment: I expect it to return 20 in latter case

Comment: But in your code you wont know what that 20 stands for. If there is no standard, how are you supposed to know what type it is. It could be px, em, %.

Comment: There can be cases where I know. I do not want to convert that px value again back to %. but my bad I forgot that I can get the applied value using .css()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/height/):

> The difference between .css('height') and .height() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px).

Comment: yes but I have set that height to 20% then it should return value unit less intact right i.e. 20

Comment: No. If you want the actual pixel height, use `height()`, but if you want to get the height provided by CSS, use `css('height')`.

Comment: It does not matter how do you set the width/height, it is ALWAYS converted to screen pixels by the browser, respectively jQuery, because it is matter of fixed screen 2D workspace plane.

Answer (score 3):

It's the most logical unit to return - most other units are relative (ems, percent). Also, it's how the browser deals with dimensions internally.

Comment: ok. u mean if I set the dimension to 20% then browser would convert it to 200px and then apply it?

Answer (score 1):

this happens because `width()` and `height()` returns the *computed* width / height (as it is calculated by the browser, in pixel) , not the value you set in css (in `em`, `%` or other)

Answer (score 1):

Pixels are the standard way of measuring the exact amount. Any number without a unit is meaningless. If I told you that you have a font that's 20% height, what does that mean to you? Nothing. You need to know whether it's pt, em, or px, which are the absolute units available. Pixels are the gold standard for how to measure, since the others are relative to font-size and other considerations.